# Progress Bar: set location/position in Canvas

Tags: android, canvas

I have set up a canvas in android that successfully draws the graphics I with. I wanted to introduce a progress bar to update the player on their progress. So far Ii have managed to have the progress bar drawn, as designed, and even have pb.setProgress updating too.

My issue is that the progress bar is displayed in the top left corner and I want to move it into the centre. I cannot find any support for ProgressBar (I can for ProgressDialog but I don't want this).

I tried:

```
probarTrainingProgress.layout(getWidth()/2, getHeight()/2, getWidth()/2 + probarTrainingProgress.getWidth(), getHeight()/2  +probarTrainingProgress.getHeight());
```

but to no avail.

Here's my code from the canvas:

```
probarTrainingProgress.setMax(currentAttackProgressNeeded);
probarTrainingProgress.setProgress(currentAttackOverallStatistics);
probarTrainingProgress.setProgressDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.barxp));
probarTrainingProgress.draw(attackCanvas);
```

Heres my XML Code fro the ProgressBar:

```
<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/probarTrainingProgress"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_margin="1dp"
    android:indeterminate="false"
    android:progressDrawable="@drawable/barxp"
    android:visibility="gone"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Move your canvas first using [Canvas.translate](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#translate(float,%20float)) before drawing. Your code should look like this:

```
canvas.save()
canvas.translate(x, y)
view.draw(canvas)
canvas.restore()
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your idea. This isn't the solution because a) I've tried this already and b) I don't want it in the centre of the screen, I'm simply exampling how I've tried to position it in the canvas. It seems unlikely that I can't programmatically move the progress bar to any position on the screen or even     float the progress bar to, say, follow a Bitmap.

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding what you're after. What's the purpose of draw(attackCanvas)? What do you do with the canvas afterwards?

Comment: Anyway assuming you are attempting to center in a bitmap, you should use Canvas.translate to move the canvas before drawing into it.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#translate(float,%20float)   Remember to translate back afterwards. You know the size of the bitmap and you can get the size of probarTrainingProgress with getMeasuredWidth|Height()

Comment: Good luck Let me know if it works and I'll update the answer accordingly

Comment: Brilliant! This totally works for moving the progress bar to where I want it. I have a final question: how do you translate back? I tried     attackCanvas.translate(0,0); but this didn't work. I have worked around it by putting the progress bar last but would like to know how to un-translate properly.

Comment: You can either translate(-x, -y) or better, use save and restore. See my updated answer